# Generate mpeg 4 file with specific format with h.264 codec

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.264, video-codecs, mpeg4

I need a specific format in my .mp4 video file:
 1. Only I and P frames
 2. Each P frame based on only the previous (temporally) I frame
 3. An I frame every second or so

Is it possible to generate this?

It doesn't have to be small or neat, I could use even something like ffmpeg encoding a movie from jpeg stills. I can write ffmpeg code if that is needed.

Thanks

Comment: With which codec?

Comment: With the h.264 codec.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of a way to do it with ffmpeg, but if you write an encoder using libx264, you can manually set each frame type, then use reference frame invalidation on every P frame will force it to use the IDR. That’ll said, I THINK you can only reference 16 frames back, so you may need an IDR ever 16 frames. Not sure about that.

EDIT. I was able to successfully encode more than 16 P frames between IDRs with invalidation

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on the invalidation part and, perhaps, share a bit of code? I haven't used libx264 before, just ffmpeg.

Comment: Look at x264.h. It’s well documented.